# Gulp or grunt plugin to increment a value?

Tags: gulp, gruntjs

In my `package.json` file, I have a key/value pair that represents an release candidate value.

```
{
  "name": "my-product",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "rc": "1",
  ...
}
```

Is there a Gulp plugin that will increment the `rc` value for me that I can use in a task? If not how can I increment it?

Answer (score 1):

The [gulp-json-modify plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-modify) works nicely with my requirements. Steps are

```
Install the plugin
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-json-modify
```

Then in `gulpfile.js`

```
const {src, dest} = require('gulp');
const json = require(gulp-modiffy-json);

const package_json = path.join(path.dirname(__filename),'package.json');
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(package_json));
const name = pkg.name;
const patch = pkg.patch;
const rc = pkg.rc;


function bumpValue(key, value) {
    // var value = Number(patch);
    value++;
    src(['./package.json'])
      .pipe(json({
        key: key,
        value: value
      }))
      .pipe(dest('./'));
}

function bumpPatch(cb) {
    bumpValue('patch', patch);
    cb();
}
exports.bumpPatch = bumpPatch

function bumpRc(cb) {
    bumpValue('rc', patch);
    cb();
}
exports.bumpRc = bumpRc
```