# How to update both package.json and package-lock.json files in Gulp?

Tags: gulp, gruntjs

I posted, and answered, [Gulp or grunt plugin to increment a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891083/gulp-or-grunt-plugin-to-increment-a-value) . However, if I modify the function in my answer to this, it doesn't work. Notice the asterisk (`*`) to signify I want both `package.json` and package-lock.json` files to be modified.

```
function modifyValue(key, value) {
    src(['./package*.json'])
      .pipe(json({
        key: key,
        value: value
      }))
      .pipe(dest('./'));
}

function incrementPatch(cb) {
    var value = Number(patch);
    value++;
    modifyValue('patch', value);
    cb();
}
exports.incrementPatch = incrementPatch
```

When I run this command, it just spews out a JSON output. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ gulp incrementPatch -f gulpfile-version.js
```

Comment: Isn't `function incrementPatch(cb)` supposed to be `function incrementPatch(patch)`? You're not using `cb` inside your function.

Comment: I updated it, copy/paste error. the `cb()`, if i understand, stands call `callback` and makes the function async.

Comment: It turns out, my `package-lock.json` file was corrupted so it npm/gulp wasn't happy.